# Валидация XHTML

Tags: xml, xhtml

Тип документа: XHTML 1.0 Transitional
Код:

```
<label for="login"><span class="gray"><h3> Ник или ID аккаунта</h3><hr/>Укажите ник ...
```

Валидатор пишет:

> document type does not allow element "h3" here; missing one of
>   "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag

Не могу понять, что именно нужно исправить?

Comment: Чтобы отформатировать код, нажмите кнопку `{}` редактора.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте кто-нибудь, чтобы код показало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь положить блочный элемент `H3` в инлайновый элемент `span`, по феншую w3c это запрещено.

Почитайте [познавательную статью](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=241) на эту тему. Преступление № 1 как раз ваш случай.